# How to get the data to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get decimal array values in a single string variable

```
decimal[] Fld_Frmk_Param3 = { 561568, 223915, 480070, 0, 453, 7.64M, 0 };

string a=???..
```

Comment: It is not okay to edit your question to a completely different one, months after you posted your original question and got answers to it. If you want to ask a different issue, then post a *new question*.

Comment: Friend Louis,i cant able ask a new question so what..

Comment: Is there is any other alternative way to ask question in STACK  ...?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315620/1906307). It is written by one of the community managers for SO so it is as authoritative as it gets. Unfortunately, transforming your question into a completely different one *after* it has received answers is not allowed, even if you are in a ban or are rate-limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it

```
decimal[] Fld_Frmk_Param3 = { 561568, 223915, 480070, 0, 453, 7.64M, 0 };

string Result = string.Join(",", Fld_Frmk_Param3);
```

Answer (score 2):

decimal[] Fld_Frmk_Param3 = { 561568, 223915, 480070, 0, 453, 7.64M, 0 };

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (decimal res in Fld_Frmk_Param3)
        {
            sb.Append(res+",");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.Join operation:

```
decimal[] Fld_Frmk_Param3 = { 561568, 223915, 480070, 0, 453, 7.64M, 0 };
string a = String.Join(", ", Fld_Frmk_Param3);
```

Gives you:

```
"561568, 223915, 480070, 0, 453, 7.64M, 0"
```